# Renewing E*TRADE oauth token using DevDefined.OAuth

Tags: c#, php, oauth, etrade-api

I successfully use E*TRADE's php sdk to create and renew oauth access tokens. However, I also need to be able to use & renew these tokens from a c# application. I tried using the c# oauth library [DevDefined OAuth Etrade](https://github.com/Investars/DevDefined.OAuth.Etrade) (just to renew a token). However, I am getting an error back from E*TRADE when trying to renew a token: oauth_problem=nonce_used. I looked in the source code for the oauth library and it uses windows GUID's to generate the nonce, thus it is highly unlikely that it would have been used before. 
Has anyone encountered and solved this? Or is there a better c# library I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using [DevDefined Oauth Etrade](https://github.com/Investars/DevDefined.OAuth.Etrade), I used [SappWorks Stocks Public](https://github.com/bmsapp/sappworks.stocks.public), and that was able to renew just fine.